# Web Server that has 2 Wifi connection (1 proxy & 1 ordinary)

Tags: networking, proxy, wifi, esp8266

I have a computer that we use as a local web server. It is normally connected to the Proxy Wifi.

I have made several ESP8266 devices but ESP8266 only connects to none proxy wifi. Hence, I cannot connect to my local web server.

Is there a way on making my local web server connect to both Proxy and Non-Proxy Wifi at the same time, and still be accessed by ESP8266 from Non-Proxy Wifi network and by PC Clients from the Proxy Wifi Network? My Local Web Server or Web Page should be accessed by both networks.

By the way, our IT department does not permit my ESP8266 be registered to the Proxy Wifi Connection. :( That is why I am having this problem. Besides, I also wasn't able to find a way in the internet for my ESP8266 be connected to Proxy Wifi Connection.

Answer (score 0):

WiFi is an infrastructure for your webserver. Webservers cannot connect to a network, but runs on. You cannot have two connections via one interface.

My suggestion is; use your web content or code as client implementation and do a basic websocket server implementation on a remote host or onto your local computer with external IP. Use websockets between client to server and device to server.

So you can access it wherever you want.